Should I leave holes when I retopologize?
I have made a character and I do retopology in the head. I was wondering if I should leave holes or not? (for example eyes and mouth). Or can I leave it as it is?


I usually see models with holes in the eye sockets and mouth, but it depends on your requirements. Do you need holes or not? This question seems opinion based and may be closed as off-topic.
